# WP Gallery showing captions twice

Tags: gallery, title, captions

I am using standard WP gallery to display images. I have added caption to every image, image title was not changed so it is same like file name. When I open one image in gallery it shows caption text in span class "TitleText". This is ok but with some images it shows the same text and it display span TitleText and span CaptionText. You can see it here:
http://www.tandem.sk/galeria/automobilizmus/cerpacie-stanice/
If you click on first image caption is showing twice, however second image is working fine. The text you see is set as caption in gallery.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a plugin to generate the lightbox or is it code that you wrote?

Comment: I am using wp-jquery-lightbox plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `WP Jquery Lightbox` plugin is generating these extra captions.

Check out the source of the [`jquery.lightbox.js`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-jquery-lightbox/trunk/jquery.lightbox.js) file:

```
        ... cut ...

        var s = '';
        if (title != '') {
            s = '<span id="titleText">' + title + '</span>';
        } 
        if (caption != '') {
            if (title != ''){
                s += '<br />';
            } 
            s += '<span id="captionText">' + caption +'</span>';
        }           

       ... cut ...
```

where you can have both a *title* and a *caption* for each image.

The *title* part is picked up from the image link title, the image title or the image alt attribute:

```
        if (this.title) { //title of link
            title = this.title;
        } else if (jqImg.attr('title')) {
            title = jqImg.attr('title'); //grab the title from the image if the link lacks one
        } else if(jqImg.attr('alt')){
            title = jqImg.attr('alt'); //if neither link nor image have a title attribute
        }
```

In your case it seems to be the image alt attribute.

If the image caption is equal to the image alt attribute, then you should only get the title part.

So to get rid of the duplications, you make sure the image *alt* attribute is the same as the image *caption*. Notice that the comparison is made after this replacement:

```
    captionText = $.trim(captionText).replace('&#8217;', '&#039;').replace('â€™', '\''); //http://nickjohnson.com/b/wordpress-apostrophe-vs-right-single-quote
    if (title.toLowerCase() == captionText.toLowerCase()) {
        title = caption; //to keep linked captions
        caption = ''; //but not duplicate the text                              
    }
```

Comment: so how should i repair it? Use different plugin?

Comment: well it is set in alternative text. I have checked it and it is set exactly the same for working and for not working images

Comment: Look closer, it's a tiny difference ;-)

Comment: trust me I have looked closer. I have set image title and image caption at every image ... no alt text is set at wordpress and still some images works and some dont

Comment: I have been using this plugin for years and I have never encountered something similar. However I did udate of WP to 3.9 today so maybe thats the issue

Comment: If you check the first image, the title and the caption do not have the same kind of dash. One is slightly longer. Check out the informative [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Comment: yeah but it was set the same in wp ... it looks like wordpress edits my text somehow but only in captions to make it gramatically correct

Comment: Try to remove the dash, just to test it.

Comment: yeah it is working without dash ... now I need to determine why wordpress makes this – from this - automatically and how to turn it off